# Does recommended creepage distance apply to copper planes under soldermasks?

Tags: pcb-design, high-voltage, solder-mask, ul, creepage

I have a design that requires around 0.5mm of creepage distance between conductors.
[TI said in this video](https://youtu.be/B696dApeUeM?t=52) that "creepage is the shortest distance between two uninsulated conductors along the surface of an insulating material". However, [I've also read that soldermask cannot be considered as true insulators.](https://www.circuitnet.com/experts/87952.html)

So my questions is, does creepage distance:

1. apply to adjacent copper planes covered by soldermask, for example, like the image below:
   [image]

or,

2. does it only apply to exposed copper/conductors not covered by soldermask, as shown in the image below?
   [image]

*Note: Orange is the copper planes that are covered by soldermask, Green is the exposed copper pad.

Am I correct to assume it's number 1?

Answer (score 7):

### TL;DR

> Does recommended creepage distance apply to copper planes under soldermasks?

Yes, it does. Solder mask does not change the required creepage distance on a circuit board.

### Is Solder Mask an Insulator?

> TI said in this video that "creepage is the shortest distance between two uninsulated conductors along the surface of an insulating material". However, I've also read that soldermask cannot be considered as true insulators.

The statement "soldermask cannot be considered as true insulators" must be considered within its context. Why do we say that it cannot be considered as a true insulator? Because this layer is extremely thin and easily scrapped off the board. So it should not be used as *vertical insulation for metal objects above the solder mask*, such as metal connectors, shields, solder pins or pads of a chip, another circuit board, etc. This is why the recommended layouts of many connectors specify large keepout zones under their bodies to avoid manufacturing defects.

But for *horizontal insulation* between two pieces of copper on the same circuit board, adding a layer of solder mask is acceptable. Basically, the actual insulator here is the FR-4 circuit board material, solder mask does not change this fact. The worst-case scenario: the solder mask is scrapped off, who cares? The FR-4 circuit board material continues to function as the insulator.

### IPC-2221 vs IEC standards vs Experience

What do industry standards say about solder mask?

#### IPC-2221

First we have IPC-2221, a voluntary industry standard used by circuit board manufacturers for quality control (not safety). According to this standard, solder mask is beneficial. It classifies solder mask as type B4 (*external conductors, with permanent polymer coating*). Comparing it to type B2 (*external conductors, uncoated, sea level to 3050 m*), type B4 significantly reduces the electrical spacing required between the conductors. For example, at 100 V, bare copper (including soldering pads) must maintain a separation distance of 0.6 mm, but traces with solder mask only need a 0.13 mm separation.

However, when we're talking about "creepage" and "clearance", it's inappropriate and wrong to use the IPC-2221 standard as our reference, since IPC-2221 is not a safety standard and does not distinguish or even define "creepage" or "clearance".

The required "creepage" or "clearance" are defined in the context of electrical safety regulations, based on a series of international standards, including IEC 60950-1, IEC 62368-1, IEC 61010-1, and IEC 60664-1. I'll use IEC 60950-1 as a representative example here.

### Safety Regulations

#### Differences

Unlike IPC-2221 - a voluntary quality standard that covers only circuit boards, IEC 60950-1 is (at least *was*) often a legal standard and is used to design safe electrical equipment under a variety of materials, use conditions, required degree of safety, including protecting humans lives from electrical shock.

The IPC-2221 only defines a single separation distance called "electrical spacing". IEC 60950-1, on the other hand, defines two different separating distances, one is called "clearance" - the distance between two conductors in air, another "creepage" - the distance between two conductors on the surface of a solid insulator. Both clearance and creepage depend on insulation type (functional/basic/reinforced), usage condition (pollution degree). For creepage, it's also a function of  material (Material Group / Comparative Tracking Index), because different materials react differently to surface contamination.

IEC 60950-1 realized that, because of surface tracking due to dust contamination, often the separation distance on the surface of a solid must be increased to obtain a reasonable safety margin. And to protect humans from electrical shock, an even higher (2x) safety margin is added to the creepage distance.

Overall, if safety is not critical in your circuit, it's reasonable to use the smaller electrical spacing numbers in IPC-2221 (including the use of the solder mask clause to reduce separation). It's acceptable even in IEC 60950-1, it's called "functional insulation", insulation required only for the correct operating of the circuit with no protection, it's mostly unregulated. But if a short circuit may cause a fire, or if failure of insulation may create an electrical shock hazard, do use IEC 60950-1 Basic Insulation and Reinforced Insulation.

In general, the required separation distances by IEC 60950-1 are much greater than IPC-2221. So if safety is unimportant in a particular case, there's strong motivation to use the smaller number in IPC-2221. But it's also worth noting that, sometimes IEC 60950-1 can give smaller clearance distance than IPC-2221, because the IEC standard allows linear interpolation but the IPC standard does not. Intuitively, going from 100 V to 101 V should not cause a large jump of electrical spacing, yet IPC-2221 requires so. [One designer](https://www.smpspowersupply.com/ipc2221pcbclearance.html) criticized the IPC-2221 requirements as "mostly baseless".

#### Solder Mask

Then what does IEC 60950-1 say about solder mask and insulation? A lot, but for most people it means very little. Under IEC 60950-1, insulators are classified into four Material Groups based on their Comparative Tracking Index (CTI). Most FR-4 circuit board substrates have a CTI of 175 or greater, and belong to Material Group IIIa. The solder mask material may be unknown, thus, is classified as Metarial Group IIIb by default. However, both IIIa and IIIb are the worst kinds of insulators, and the standard gives the same creepage distance requirements. Hence, the presence of solder mask does not make a difference, end of the story.

To be fair, IEC 60950-1 does not exclude the possibility of using coating (both solder mask and conformal coating) with a better Material Group on a circuit board's surface to improve insulation and reduce creepage requirements as well. But it's only possible with additional quality control requirements. It states that "manufacturing is subjected to a quality control programme that provides at least the same level of assurance" and "The coating process, the coating material and the base material shall be such that uniform quality is assured and the separation distances under consideration are effectively protected." For a mass-produced generic circuit board found in consumer electronics, these requirements are rarely met. Even if one decides to go with this expensive route, one is more likely to use a type of conformal coating specifically designed for this purpose, rather than trying to control the generic solder mask.

Thus, for the purpose of regulation, using solder mask or not does not make a difference (a real conformal coating, on the other hand, does make a difference). You simply proceeds as if it's a bare board.

### Experience

From experience, many circuit boards remove the solder mask across an insulation barrier in an attempt to increase its safety. Presumably, the reasoning is the following: the circuit board substrate, FR-4, is a material provided by its manufacturers with controlled electrical properties, on the other hand, a generic type of solder mask's electrical properties are poorly controlled. Thus, it's possible that solder mask has worse insulation than a bare circuit board.

I'm open to correction, but for most designs, so far I didn't find any regulatory requirements to do so. The circuit board substrate belongs to Material Group IIIa. The solder mask, due to its unknown electrical properties, is classified as Material Group IIIb by default. Both are treated as the worst kinds of insulators, and the standard gives identical creepage requirements. Thus, the poor material is already accounted for by the large spacing rules.

The only argument for mandatory solder mask removal comes from a small fine-print in the standard:

> Material Group IIIb is not recommended for applications in Pollution Degree 3 with an RMS working voltage above 630 V.

Thus, an argument can be made to remove solder mask for this application, since a circuit board is guaranteed to be Material Group IIIa, but the unknown solder mask can be Material Group IIIb, which the standards warn against. Still, most electronics for home, office, and lab uses are designed for Pollution Degree 2 (non-conductive dust), not Pollution Degree 3, thus, no regulatory requirement exists for most designs at any voltage.

So the conclusion is that, it can be a good design practice, but it only has a small benefit with diminishing return, and it's not required by the regulation in general (which already accounts for the poor materials used and requires a large spacing).

Finally, there are always exceptions. Some circuit boards may be designed with a special material with higher Comparative Tracking Index (CTI), upgrading it from Material Group IIIa/IIIb to Group II or even Group I. In this case, if the board is manufactured with a generic type of solder mask, you definitely want to remove it across a critical insulation barrier. Conversely, special solder mask with high CTI also exists. But in practical, both cases are exceedingly rare.

### Summary

In general, solder mask does not change the required creepage distance on a circuit board. According to the industry quality standard IPC-2221, solder mask improves insulation. According to international safety standards, in general, a generic circuit board belongs to Material Group IIIa, a solder mask material with unknown electrical properties belong to Material Group IIIb, both have the same creepage distance requirements. Thus, solder mask usually does not change anything.

When conductive dust is present (Pollution Degree 3), the working voltage is above 630 V, and when the solder mask's electrical property is unknown, removing solder mask across an insulation barrier is justified based on a warning in the safety standards. However, most electronics for home, office, and lab uses are designed for Pollution Degree 2 (non-conductive dust), thus, no regulatory requirement exists to remove solder mask for most designs at any voltage.

For the purpose of regulation, it's also possible to use solder mask with a better Material Group to improve insulation and reduce creepage (not clearance) requirements, but production must be under quality control according to regulatory requirements. This is rarely the case for mass-produced customer-grade circuit boards. Even if one decides to go with this expensive route, one is more likely to use a type of conformal coating specifically designed for this purpose, rather than trying to control the generic solder mask.

Comment: My reading of IEC 60950-1 was that, solder mask would count as an insulative coating *with an approved inspection procedure*. (I'm not sure if that would involve per-article or sampled process inspection. Also this was some years ago so I've forgotten a bit, and 60950 is now deprecated anyway.)

Comment: @TimWilliams Good point. I rechecked and noticed 60950 does not even mention "conformal" coating. Any kind of coating, if tested and approved, can be used to relax separation requirements. Otherwise the default rules apply, and for unknown material I believe it's always Material Group IIIb. I'll write a paragraph on that. Also interestingly, in the old version of 60950, all PCB materials received a special treatment in Table 2N, only require roughly half the creepage, but it was eventually removed in newer versions and 62368. Not sure what happened. The regulators lost their confidence?

Answer (score 2):

Both need to be considered but for your main concern, the uncoated creepage to considered is #2

IPC-2221 captures the recommended spacing requirements and the two "device types" concerned here are

1. B2 - External Conductors, uncoated, sea level. This applied to the exposed pads
2. B4 - External Conductors, with permanent polymer coating. This applies to the copper zones with solder mask
3. A6 - External Components lead/termination, uncoated. This applies to the populated card

For a given voltage, the distances for B2 are larger than B4 as you can take credit for the insulation properties of the solder mask. This means you "orange zones" gap can be smaller than the "green pad" separation.

Personally, I always use conformal coating for high-voltage applications. Not only due to the pollution level being considered but also its a 2nd line of defense with respect to a possible quality issue with the solder mask.
Solder masks primary goal is to protect the copper and while it does offer insulative properties the thickness and dielectric strength are not controlled and thus to take credit could be considered a risk

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. IPC-2221 is a voluntary industrial standard, primarily for circuit board quality control, not safety. Its electrical spacing rule does not distinguish creepage and clearance, does not consider surface tracking due to contamination, and also allows the use of solder mask as a type of polymer coating to reduce the spacing. For safety-critical insulation, one must use a safety standard according to the regulation instead, often IEC 60950-1. This standard gives a lower clearance and a higher creepage. PCBs with or without solder mask are considered the same.